# Configuring Postgres database with Liferay

Tags: database, postgresql, hook, liferay

I want to connect my liferay to another Postgres database, and to recover the username and login for user from this database and to connect to liferay with this data. I am using a hook but I don't know which file or jsp page to modify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the `portal.properties` for the configuration:

```
# PostgreSQL
#
#jdbc.default.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
#jdbc.default.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/lportal
#jdbc.default.username=sa
#jdbc.default.password=
```